# distraction free word processors which can work on a secondary screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, text-editors, word-processing

I'm a bit of a fan of distraction free word processors - currently i prefer [q10](http://www.baara.com/q10/), but there's a small issue for me - I tend to use a two screen setup for serious writing, either cause i have information in note form on a second word processor/notepad type programme, or for quick lookups of information on the internet.

I need to have the task bar accessible for these things, but for that, i'd need to have a word processor on a second screen, and have the random other stuff i do on the primary.

So, are there any full screen, customisable, distraction free word processors which i can switch/move across screens?

Notepad is not an option. I need customisable backgrounds and forgrounds, and ideally spellcheck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, I found these work with dual screens. I have both installed but I always use Writemonkey because it comes with Markdown support:

- [Ommwriter](http://www.ommwriter.com/en/frequently-meditated-questions.html)
- [Writemonkey](http://writemonkey.com/)

For Writemonkey, pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> takes it out of full-screen mode. Just move the window around to the other screen then press <kbd>Esc</kbd> again. Pressing <kbd>F7</kbd> activates spell-check

Comment: I just wish Writemonkey has the same horizontal cursor that Ommwriter has. For zen purposes and whatnot.

Comment: writemonkey works perfectly for my needs. Sorry about the delay, but i was a little busy and couldn't check if it worked as i needed it to.